# accessing siblings in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, node.js

I'm writing a node application and I would like to get the name of the variable that invokes a constructor.

```
a=new constructorFunction();
b=new constructorFunction();

function constructorFunction(){
    this.test="it works!";
    this.doSomething=function(){
       //this should return the contents of this.test
    }
}

console.log(a.doSomething());
console.log(b.doSomething());
```

As the comment says, I'd like to return the values of a.test and b.test. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: When I console.log(this.test) within this.doSomething() it returns undefined.

Comment: Then the code you posted doesn't match the code you have.

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1732-THIS-Function-Context-And-Object-Literals-In-Javascript.htm - so at the time of definition, `this` is `constructorFunction`

Comment: But in the definition of doSomething, there is a `return this.test;` ?? if is not, then there's your answer!

Comment: `this` is the context, it is whatever object you're calling the function on.

Comment: Derrr. I oversimplified my code to make an example and missed an obvious bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't need to be any more complicated than this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjzaworski/yS44n/)):

```
function constructorFunction() {
  this.test="it works!";
  this.doSomething = function() {
    return this.test;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd give it an upvote if `doSomething` was on `constructorFunction.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=new constructorFunction();
b=new constructorFunction();

function constructorFunction(){
    var self = this;
    this.test="it works!";
    this.doSomething=function(){
       return self.test;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In chrome this works... (V8 so I assume node.js will behave the same)

http://jsfiddle.net/zTTZR/1/

```
a=new constructorFunction();
b=new constructorFunction();

function constructorFunction(){
    this.test="it works!";
    this.doSomething=function(){
       return this.test;
    }
}

console.log(a.doSomething());
```